# fork() causes column headers to print for each process

Tags: c, fork, printf

I'm writing a simple C program using fork() to create a binary tree of processes. I am able to get all the output I need (pid's of process, its parent, and its two children). Unfortunately, each forked process wants to print out the column headers. How do I make sure that the printf for the headers is executed only once?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

//Declarations
int i;
int child_1_pid, child_2_pid;
int num_levels = atoi(argv[1]);

//Output banners
//execlp("/bin/echo", "echo", "Level\tProcs\tParent\tChild1\tChild2\nNo.\tID\tID\tID\tID", (char *) NULL);
//if(getpid() > 0)
printf("Level\tProcs\tParent\tChild1\tChild2\nNo.\tID\tID\tID\tID");

//Creates binary tree of processes
for(i = 0; i < num_levels; i++){
    if((child_1_pid = fork()) && (child_2_pid = fork())){
        printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", i, getpid(), getppid(), child_1_pid, child_2_pid);
        sleep(2); //prevents parent from terminating before child can get ppid (parent's pid)
        break; //why?       
    }   
}//end for

printf("\n"); //EXPLAIN ME!!
exit(0);
}//end main
```

There's some more code (error checking really), but my real problem is that the printf under the output banners section executes multiple times, giving output like this (but correctly aligned):

> ```
> Level Procs   Parent  Child1  Child2
> No.   ID  ID  ID  ID
> No.   ID  ID  ID  ID
> No.   ID  ID  ID  ID
> No.   ID  ID  ID  ID
> No.   ID  ID  ID  ID
> No.   ID  ID  ID  ID
> No.   ID  ID  ID  ID
> 0 30796   24743   30797   30798
> 1 30797   30796   30799   30800
> 1 30798   30796   30801   30802
> ```

I've tried a few ideas (including those commented out under the banner section), but nothing seems to work and most "fixes" make the problem even worse!

Comment: I think I can explain the weird printing you're seeing. Your `sleep(2)` and `printf("\n")` could be `fflush(0)`s.

Comment: Does adding `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` fix anything?  It could be that the stdio buffers are being copied into the child processes and only printed there.

Comment: Yes! Adding fflush does fix the multiple print problem. I also removed the \n print at the bottom to avoid excess blank lines. Also, as noted below, I had to put a fflush after the process print line (inside the for loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `if` in the for-loop does not behave as you want it to. Remember that after the fork, it returns the child PID in the parent process and 0 in the child. So inside the loop, the first fork assigns a value to child_1_pid in the parent and continues to the second clause. The child does not enter the `if` but continues to the next for-loop iteration. The very same happens with the second clause. So only the main process should ever be able to enter the body of the `if`, but no child process. I wonder why the output suggests otherwise.

So to get your "binary tree", you should actually have this:

```
// COMPLETELY UNTESTED
for(i = 0; i < num_levels; i++){
    if (!(child_1_pid = fork()) || !(child_2_pid = fork())) {
        printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", i, getpid(), getppid(), child_1_pid, child_2_pid);
        // A child process, go on to next iteration.
        continue;
    }

    // A parent process. Wait for children, then stop.
    if (child_1_pid) wait();
    if (child_2_pid) wait();
    break;
}
```

The strange output of the banners has to do with flushing of streams. Normally, fprintf only flushed on newline (`\n`), IIRC. So there's still stuff in the buffer after the fork that has not been flushed yet, and each child runs `printf("\n");` and thus flushes out the buffer content.

The solution is to either add a "\n" to the end of the very first printf, or call `fflush(stdout);` before the `for` loop.

Comment: You are completely right about the need for the fflush before the for loop. I also had to add one after the banner print statement. Thanks for the tip about printf and flushing on newlines....that cleared things up.

Comment: this will create an unbalanced binary tree as only the parent process from the first call to `fork()` will `fork()` a second time due to short circuiting. This may or may not be your intention.

Comment: @SiegeX: You're right. Using `|` instead of `||` should fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to try, although I'm a little rusty with this stuff. In the line where you print out your banners:

> printf("Level\tProcs\tParent\tChild1\tChild2\nNo.\tID\tID\tID\tID");

It may be that everything after the `\n` is being left in the ouput buffer, so it's still there when each child is forked. Try adding another `\n` at the end of that `printf`, and removing the `\n` from the beginning of the `printf` inside the loop.

Comment: I think this is the right idea. The above answer mentioned that printf flushes on \n, so you seem to be correct.

Comment: @John Smith Yep. @DarkDust definitely had a more thorough answer than I, though.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
printf("Level\tProcs\tParent\tChild1\tChild2\nNo.\tID\tID\tID\tID");
```

With:

```
puts("Level\tProcs\tParent\tChild1\tChild2\nNo.\tID\tID\tID\tID");
```

Replace:

```
printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", i, getpid(), getppid(), child_1_pid, child_2_pid);
```

With:

```
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, getpid(), getppid(), child_1_pid, child_2_pid);
```

Remove:

```
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Read 2.5.1 here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html

> Note that after a fork(), two handles exist where one existed before. The application shall ensure that, if both handles can ever be accessed, they are both in a state where the other could become the active handle first. The application shall prepare for a fork() exactly as if it were a change of active handle. (If the only action performed by one of the processes is one of the exec functions or _exit() (not exit()), the handle is never accessed in that process.)

What this means is that, before calling `fork` you should call `fflush` on any streams that you intend to use in both processes after the `fork`.